# comma separated array of hex string with control characters to byte array

Tags: arrays, string, sockets, hex

I guess its very simple but it wasted my time a lot but still no luck!

the following is working very nicely-

```
sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
byte[] bytes=new byte[]{0x7F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x21, 0x09, 0x7F, 0x30, 0x00, 0x15, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00, 0xEE, 0x28, 0xCB, 0x87 };
sck.Connect("192.168.1.100", 8008);
sck.Send(bytes);
sck.Close();
```

and, if I keep those array of hex strings in a text box like-

```
textbox1.Text="0x7F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x21, 0x09, 0x7F, 0x30, 0x00, 0x15, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00, 0xEE, 0x28, 0xCB, 0x87";
```

But, I need to use the textbox1.Text string for the same task; like-

```
sck.Send(textbox1.Text);
```

I tried a lot but could not come up with any solution. Please guide me...

In fact, I'll keep the hex string in the database as string and will be retrieved later in my program.

Comment: Which language? Tag the appropriate language in the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the difference between a `string` and a `byte array` is :

```
"0x03" as a string is of 4 bytes
 0x03 as an entry in a byte array is of 1 byte
```

So what you need to do is `Delimit` the string at `,` and separate different hexadecimal strings, store them in a string array or any other data structure.

Then you have to convert these strings to a single byte using some function or you can create your own method, one of them can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java).

Store these `bytes` in a `byte array` and you're good to go.

Comment: Hi Mohit, thank you for such nice idea. I also thought to do in that way. Though I was looking for if there is anything very simple method or builtin function.

Comment: yeah there are some built-in functions, but they have some limitations, thats why I suggested you to just develop your own function or follow the link mentioned above.

Comment: I did it! Thanks Mohit.

Comment: Well if you did get help from my answer, you should have accepted it.

Comment: Hi Mohit, May be I've accepted. Previously I didn't notice it. Because, I am not regular to Stack. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Yeah it's cool, I'm sure your problem has been solved, isnt it?

Comment: Yes. It was solved. Bellow is the answer (Ans no 2). I request you to accept my answer also. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did it the following way:

```
txtHexString.Text="0x11, 0x01, 0x49, 0x4D, 0x41, 0x47, 0x45, 0x31, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x53, 0x75, 0x6D, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x72, 0x79, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00";

string[] namesArray =  txtHexString.Text.Split(',');
byte[] abc= new byte [namesArray.Length];

for (int i = 0; i <= namesArray.Length - 1; i = i + 1)
        {
            abc[i] = Convert.ToByte(namesArray[i].Replace(" ", ""), 16);
        }
```

here, abc is the desired byte array.